# create an html file from batch

Tags: html, batch-file, batch-processing

I am writing a batch script to generate an HTML code.  I have everything working correctly but can't seem to get this one line to echo to the HTML code!  Where do I place the "^" or other character to get this line of code to echo to the HTML code without generating an error??

```
echo ^<td align="center" width="50%"^> >>%website%
```

I know how to do it in PowerShell and Python, but would like to know how in batch. thanks in advance for any advice or help!

Comment: PROBLEM CORRECTED!  I changed 50% to 50%% and it worked nicely!  I hope my solution and question helps someone else!

Comment: Thank you Tiw, for your fast response, but I found and corrected it myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `%`, That's also a place need to escape. You can use `%%` instead.

Comment: Yes I completely forgot about that!  Something so simple it slipped my mind.  Thanks again!